# Thread how to change sleep time

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

In my project I have function as defined below:

```
void start(std::chrono::milliseconds delay) override
{
    mDelay = delay;
    if(mThread == nullptr)
    {
        mThread = std::make_unique<Thread>([&]()
        {
            sleep(std::chrono::milliseconds(mDelay));
        });
    }
}
```

When I call the method for first time the thread is created and goes to sleep for mDelay period. But I need to change the mDelay time again but for a lesser time period than the earlier one supplied.

But when I call it again I am unable to cancel the previous sleep and start a new one with defined mDelay?

How can I achieve the same?

Comment: you need an event loop, with services feeding events into that loop. One such thing is `boost::asio`.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need a pointer here. Use a member: `std::thread thr;`. When the object is constructed, the thread object's default constructor will create a thread object with no thread of execution. You can test for this with `thr.get_id() == std::thread::id()`, and if no thread has been started, you can start one with `thr = std::thread(/* your stuff */)`.

Comment: Your thread has no side effects; the simplest solution is to not create a thread at all.  If you meant to have the thread invoke some code (a "trigger"), before a good answer can be written you need to express what happens when (a) the old trigger already fired, (b) the new delay moves the trigger time up, or (c) down, and (d) what should happen if the app shuts down while waiting.  The nature of the trigger also matters; is it thread safe?  Can it block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move and dispose old thread ( from mobile, code not tested). If the thread were to trigger a handler, just raise a killed flag so that the disposed thread will not triggered once killed.

```
 if(mThread != nullptr)
 {
     auto dispose = std::move(mThread);
     dispose->detach();
     mThread.reset(new Thread([&]()
    {
        sleep(std::chrono::milliseconds(mDelay));
    });
  }
```

Comment: This looks like advice that will generate code with race conditions all over it.

Answer (score 2):

I see what you are trying to do, I believe [`std::condition_variable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) is what you are searching for.

Instead of sleep, you can call `wait_for`. When you want to wake the thread, you can call `notify_one`.

Answer (score 1):

Once the thread has been created for the first time, `mThread` is never reset after the thread finishes its work.  The next time `start()` is called, `mThread` is not `nullptr` anymore, and thus a new thread is not created with the updated `delay`.

Either the `Thread` lambda needs to reset `mThread` to `nullptr` before exiting, or else `Thread` needs a `bool` member that the lambda can set before exiting.  Either way will allow `start()` to know when a new thread is needed.